# Text along an ark in a circle pack Text placement wrong

Tags: d3.js

I found a similar question on stack overflow. Using that code I got some text showing but it is not in the the right place.  It is way off the chart, but it is curved and the content of the text is right.

This is my code and a fiddle.  Any help would be great!

```
 function polarToCartesian(centerX, centerY, radius, angleInDegrees) 
{  var angleInRadians = (angleInDegrees - 90) * Math.PI / 180.0;
return {  x: centerX + (radius * Math.cos(angleInRadians)),
        y: centerY + (radius * Math.sin(angleInRadians))
    };
}

function describeArc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle) {
    var start = polarToCartesian(x, y, radius, endAngle);
    var end = polarToCartesian(x, y, radius, startAngle);
    var arcSweep = endAngle - startAngle <= 180 ? "0" : "1";
    var d = [
        "M", start.x, start.y,
        "A", radius, radius, 0, 1, 1, end.x, end.y
    ].join(" ");
    return d;
}

var arcs = node.append("path")
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("id", function (d, i) { return "s" + i; })
    .attr("d", function (d, i) {
        return describeArc(d.x, d.y, d.r, 160, -160)
    });

var arcPaths = node.append("g")
    .style("fill", "black");

var labels = arcPaths.append("text")
    .style("opacity", function (d) {
        if (d.depth == 0) {
            return 0.0;
        } else {
            return 0.8;
        }})
    .attr("font-size", 10)
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .append("textPath")
    .attr("xlink:href", function (d, i) { return "#s" + i; })
    .attr("startOffset", function (d, i) { return "50%"; })
    .text(function (d) { return d.data.key == "root" ? "" : 
     d.data.key; })
```

[circle pack with textpath](http://jsfiddle.net/jwaldner/k03c7ku2/)

Comment: Can you show how you are defining the "defs" - the paths that you are referencing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 This is what worked for me...



  function updateSetupData(data) {

    var countsByParent = d3.nest()
       .key(function (d) { return d.parent + '_tbl'; })
       .key(function (d) { return d.SkillGroup + '_grp'; })
        //.key(node => node.AgtName)
        //.rollup(function(leaves) { return leaves.length;})
       .entries(data);


    var treeRoot = {
        key: "root",
        parent: null,
        value: "100",
        values: countsByParent };

    var root = d3.hierarchy(treeRoot, function (d) { return d.values; })
     .sum(function (d) { return d.value; });
    // .sort(function(a, b) { return b.value - a.value; });

    var nodes = pack(root);

    //console.log(nodes);

    var node = canvas.selectAll(".node")
        .data(pack(root).descendants())
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", function (d) {
            return d.data.key == null ? "node " + d.data.AgtName  + " agent " : "node " + d.data.key + " cir";
        })
        .attr("id", function (d) { return d.data.AgtName + "a_" + d.data.AgtId + "_s" + d.data.skillId + "_g" + d.data.groupId })
        .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
        .attr("fill", "steelblue")
        .on("mouseover", function (d) {
            highlight(d.label ? d.label : d.data.AgtName);
        }).on("mouseout", function (d) { highlight(null); });

    function highlight(agtName) {
        if (agtName == null) d3.selectAll(".node").classed("active", false);
        else d3.selectAll(".node." + agtName).classed("active", true);
    }

  node.append("circle")
        .attr("r", function (d) { return d.r;  })
      // .attr("fill", "steelblue")
        .attr("opacity", 0.25)
        .attr("stroke", "#ADADAD")
        .attr("stroke-width", "2");

    node
     .append("svg:title").text(function (d) { return d.data.AgtName; });

    var arc = arcGenerator
        .outerRadius(function (d, i) { return d.r; })
        .startAngle(0)
        .endAngle(180);

    node.append('defs')
   .append('path')
   .attr("id", function (d, i) { return "s" + i; })
   .attr("d", arc);

    //.attr("d", function (d, i) { return getPathData(d.r); } );

    node.append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(90)")
        .attr("text-anchor", function (d) { return  d.data.key == null ? 
         "start" :  d.data.key.split("_") [1] === "tbl" ? "end" : "start";})
        .append("textPath")
        .attr("startOffset", '50%')
        .attr("xlink:href", function (d, i) { return '#s' + i; })
        .attr("fill", function (d) { return  d.data.key == null ? "none" : 
         d.data.key.split("_") [1] === "tbl" ? "blue" : "black"; })
        .text(function (d) {
            return d.data.key == null ? "" :
            d.data.key == "root" ? "" : d.data.key.split("_")[0];
        });


};
```

Answer (score 0):

The `href` of `textPath` should link to `path` element, link to circle will not work. You could create an invisible path along the circle and link to that in `textPath`. Check out this example: http://bl.ocks.org/jebeck/196406a3486985d2b92e